# How to make method in repository like GreaterThanOrEquals in Spring Data Rest..?

Tags: spring-data-rest

How to make method on entity like GreaterThanOrEquals in Spring Data Rest..?

Entity class looks like below.

```
Class Demo {
private Long id;
private Long number;
}
```

Repository class looks like below.

```
interface DemoRepository extends JPARepository<Demo, Long>{

  Collection<Demo> findByIdAndNumberGreaterThanZero(Long id, Long number);

}
```

The above code will works.? If not so how could i achieve this with out @Query.?

Comment: The above method findByIdAndNumberGreaterThanZero should not works i think, is there any way to do that..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method name is mistyped it should be findByIdAndNumberGreaterThan**Equal**, not findByIdAndNumberGreaterThan**Zero**.

```
Collection<Demo> findByIdAndNumberGreaterThanEqual(Long id, Long number);
```

Also, if the `id` property is the actual id of the entity this method will return zero or one result. (Either the entity with the given id, if the number of that entity is greater or equal or nothing at all)

So it should be

```
Optional<Demo> findByIdAndNumberGreaterThanEqual(Long id, Long number);
```

...or if you need all of the entities where the `number` property is greater than a given value:

```
Collection<Demo> findByNumberGreaterThanEqual(Long number);
```